# Markov matrices with no ones on off-diagonals don't have -1 as an eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Every time I saw a Markov matrix with an Eigen value of -1, it had some 1's on its off-diagonals. The most obvious example is a simple permutation matrix:

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$$

With eigen values 1 and -1. As soon as you subtract $\epsilon$ from the 1's and add them to the 0's, the -1 eigen value decreases in magnitude.

For another example, see the matrix $M$ [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618263/a-problem-in-graph-theory/#comment5412086_2618900). Again, an eigen value of -1 with multiple 1's on the off-diagonals.

Is there a way to prove or refute this claim?

All I have so far are examples to support it and haven't been able to come up with a direction for how to prove it.

---

Why do I care about this result? Because I'm considering Markov matrices formed from coin flips where the coins can never be one-sided. Such matrices might have 1's on their diagonals, but never on the off-diagonals.

If this is true, we can write for such a matrix $M$,

$$vM^n = c_1+c_2\lambda_1^n+\dots$$

Since $\lambda_1$ and other eigen values must be $<1$, we can say as $n \to \infty$,

$$vM^n = c_1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to refute the claim - a counterexample.

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&\frac12&\frac12\\ 0&0&\frac12&\frac12\\ \frac12&\frac12&0&0\\ \frac12&\frac12&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue with eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Eigenvalues of $-1$ are associated with bipartite graphs; if every step alternates between two subgraphs, there will be an eigenvector for $-1$ weighting everything in one of those subgraphs positive and everything in the other negative. Other roots of unity are associated with directed cycles of longer lengths; they're less likely to come up unless you specifically rig the system to get them, but they're possible.

Comment: I thought I had... I shouldn't post so much in the wee hours, should I?

Comment: Thanks, is there a proof that alternating between subgraphs causes the matrix to have - 1 as an eigenvalue?

Comment: Actually, that's easy to see.. But how do we prove that alternating is the *only* way to get a -1?

Comment: Consider the eigenvector for $-1$. Split into positive entries and negative entries, then look at the sums for each part. Any edges within the same part work against us so it's not an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

> The only thing that can derail my argument in the blog is if the matrices have an eigen value, -1

Then eigenvalue $−1$ of the matrix $M$ does not cause big problems for the investigation, because to it correspond an eigenvalue $1$ of the matrix $M^2$, and we can consider the convergence of odd and even powers separately. This is a direction in which I 'm going to continue my answer to the linked question.

The same approach is applicable for eigenvalues $\xi$ which are roots of unity of a small order $m$. Moreover, if all entries of $n\times n$ matrix $M$ are rational, then order $[\Bbb Q(\xi):\Bbb Q]$ of the extension $\Bbb Q(\xi)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is at most $\varphi(m)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler function (see, for instance, [L, Ch. VIII, $\S$3, Theorem 6]). This allows us bound $m$ in terms of $n$ as follows.

Let $m=p_1^{m_1}\dots p_k^{m_k}$ be a product of powers of distinct primes. Then, according to [M]

$$\varphi(m)=m\left(1-\frac 1{p_1}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac 1{p_k}\right)\ge \frac{cm}{\log_e \log_e m}.$$

I guees that $c$ is a constant. Then more aysmpotically weak but more concrete lower bound for $\varphi(m)$ follows from an observation that $k\le\log_2 m$ and $1-\frac 1{p_i}\ge 1-\frac 1{i+1}$ for each $i$, so

$$\varphi(m)\ge m\frac 12\frac 23\cdots\frac k{k+1}=\frac m{k+1}\ge \frac{m}{\log_2 m +1}.$$

*References*

[L] Serge Lang, *Algebra*, Addison-Wesley Publ., 1965 (Russian translation, M.:Mir, 1968).

[M] Mathematical encyclopedia, vol. 5, 1985 (in Russian).